# Select empty if previous cell value and current cell value is same in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a situation to remove the repeating values from table based on the user name in a SQL Server stored procedure. My table look like shown in this screenshot:

[image: Table looks like this]

I am expecting the output to be like:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Result you required must be formatted in the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) Function which support for **SQL 2012+** as below, I have use ID as primary key extra in your table

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS Table
(
    ID INT,
    [Date] DateTime,
    [User] VARCHAR(50),
    SourceIp VARCHAR(50),
    Destination VARCHAR(50),
    Port INT,
    Duration VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(1,'12/27/2017 17:22','Jackson','192.168.1.1','192.168.2.1',1500,'0:38:30')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(2,'12/27/2017 23:19','Jackson','192.168.1.20','192.168.2.1',1500,'0:38:30')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(3,'12/27/2017 16:39','Manu','192.168.1.10','192.168.2.2',256,'1:00:36')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(4,'12/27/2017 21:22','Soma','192.168.5.20','192.168.2.3',888,'1:01:22')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(5,'12/27/2017 21:22','Soma','192.168.5.20','192.168.2.4',4120,'1:01:22')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(6,'12/27/2017 21:22','Soma','192.168.5.20','192.168.2.5',22,'1:01:22')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(7,'12/27/2017 8:58','Vick','192.168.1.27','192.168.2.50',22,'0:05:51')
INSERT INTO @tblTest VALUES(8,'12/27/2017 15:48','Vick','192.168.1.27','192.168.2.50',22,'0:05:51')

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN [Date] = lag([Date])  OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL ELSE [Date] END [Date] ,
    CASE WHEN [User] = lag([User])  OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN '' ELSE [User] END [User],
    CASE WHEN SourceIp = lag(SourceIp)  OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN '' ELSE SourceIp END SourceIp,
    CASE WHEN Destination = lag(Destination)  OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN '' ELSE Destination END Destination,
    CASE WHEN Port = lag(Port)  OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN NULL ELSE Port END Port,
    CASE WHEN Duration = lag(Duration)  OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN '' ELSE Duration END Duration
FROM @tblTest
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would typically handle this in your presentation layer, but you may try the following query:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date) = 1
         THEN User ELSE '' END AS User,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date) = 1
         THEN [Source IP] ELSE '' END AS [Source IP],
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date) = 1
         THEN Destination ELSE '' END AS Destination,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date) = 1
         THEN Port ELSE '' END AS Port,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date) = 1
         THEN Duration ELSE '' END AS Duration
FROM yourTable;
```

Note: It is not clear from your sample output whether you expect the `Source IP` for all records or not.  If not, then just modify my query.

This might be a viable option if your version of SQL Server does not support `LAG`.

Comment: Source IP is required, I am getting syntax error in PARTITION section in your query

Comment: @Jzl Sorry, it should read `PARTITION BY`.  I didn't test my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE(ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(20),DTE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT 1,'RAJIV',GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'RAJIV',GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'RAVI',GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'RAVI',GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'AJAY',GETDATE()
```

Select statement:

```
SELECT 
A.ID
,CASE WHEN A.R = 1 THEN A.NAME  ELSE '' END AS NAME
,A.DTE
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID)  AS R,*
FROM @TAB) A
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    DTE
1   RAJIV   2018-02-06 11:04:13.257
2           2018-02-06 11:04:13.257
3   RAVI    2018-02-06 11:04:13.257
4           2018-02-06 11:04:13.257
5   AJAY    2018-02-06 11:04:13.257
```