# How to write this SQL statement in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LabTests](
    [TestId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestName] [nvarchar](50) NULL)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestsRanges](
    [TestId] [int] NULL,
    [CatId] [int] NULL,
    [PatientSex] [int] NULL,
    [CaseId] [int] NULL,
    [LowerLimit] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [UpperLimit] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
```

Each laboratory test has reference range low range (lowerLimit) and high range (UpperLimit).
Also each test may have more than one range depends on patient male or female and patient age. 
Now my select statement show the following output:

```
select a.TestId , a.TestName , b.LowerLimit , b.UpperLimit
from LabTests  a, TestsRanges b
where a.TestId = b.TestId
order by a.TestId 

1   White Blood Cell Count  1   10
1   White Blood Cell Count  3   8
1   White Blood Cell Count  12  20
2   Red Blood Cell Count    1   20
2   Red Blood Cell Count    1   3
3   Hemoglobin Concentration    5   9
5   Mean Cell Volume    2   4.5
5   Mean Cell Volume    3   6
6   ALBUMIN         
9   FREE - T3   1   10
9   FREE - T3   3   7
10  FREE-T4 2.5 5.6
10  FREE-T4 2   4.3
```

But I dont need this dublicate test name I need the output to show test name one time only like this:

```
1   White Blood Cell Count  1   10
                            3   8
                            12  20

2   Red Blood Cell Count    1   20
                            1   3

3   Hemoglobin Concentration    5   9

5   Mean Cell Volume    2   4.5
                        3   6

9   FREE - T3   1   10
                3   7

10  FREE-T4 2.5 5.6
            2   4.3
```

Comment: Same question has been asked just before some couple of minutes please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635950/select-empty-if-previous-cell-value-and-current-cell-value-is-same-in-sql-server/48636275#48636275

Comment: my above comments seems some what match your requirement, Apply LAG function only those column which don't want to duplicate

Answer (score 2):

AS I have mention above you can check shared link, still I post below answer it may works for you, I haven't test it yet.

```
DECLARE @tblLabTests AS Table
(
    TestId INT,
    TestName VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @tblTestsRanges AS Table
(       
    TestId INT,
    LowerLimit INT,
    UpperLimit INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblLabTests VALUES(1,'White Blood Cell Count')
INSERT INTO @tblLabTests VALUES(2,'Red Blood Cell Count')
INSERT INTO @tblLabTests VALUES(3,'Hemoglobin Concentration')
INSERT INTO @tblLabTests VALUES(5,'Mean Cell Volume')   

INSERT INTO @tblTestsRanges VALUES(1,1,10)
INSERT INTO @tblTestsRanges VALUES(1,11,20)
INSERT INTO @tblTestsRanges VALUES(2,15,20)
INSERT INTO @tblTestsRanges VALUES(2,6,9)

select 
    CASE WHEN a.TestId = lag(a.TestId)  OVER (ORDER BY a.TestId) THEN '' ELSE CAST(a.TestId AS VARCHAR(50)) END TestId ,       
    CASE WHEN a.TestName = lag(a.TestName)  OVER (ORDER BY a.TestName) THEN '' ELSE CAST(a.TestName AS VARCHAR(50)) END TestName,
    b.LowerLimit , 
    b.UpperLimit
from @tblLabTests  a, @tblTestsRanges b
where a.TestId = b.TestId
order by a.TestId
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: its showing error the multipart identifier a.testid could not be found & the multipart identifier a.testname could not be found

Comment: Can you please also provide insert statement so I can work on that table and after test give you proper solution

Comment: I have update answer with sample data and it works fine.

Comment: but i dont need to show null I replaced NULL  with ' ' , null removed from the output but testid appeared 0 in second line how to remove 0 also

Comment: To replace `null` with '' you have to convert in `VARCHAR`, Check updated answer

Comment: can you add this part to the same query to show only the result with the first line only its appear now with all the rows                                                            case when coalesce([RESULT_NUMBER],'') <> '' then RESULT_NUMBER 
       when coalesce(RESULT_REPORT, '') <> '' then RESULT_REPORT 
       end AS Result

Comment: I liked your approach more than Michal's. I didn't knew those "Analytic functions" existed, No need for subqueries. _Not sure about performance with high amount of data, as it maybe orders twice_

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses only `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, quite basic query :)

```
select case when RN = 1 then TestName else '' end,
       LowerLimit , UpperLimit
from (
select a.TestId [TestId],
       a.TestName [TestName],
       b.LowerLimit [LowerLimit],
       b.UpperLimit [UpperLimit],
       row_number() over (order by b.LowerLimit partition by a.TestId , a.TestName) [RN]
from LabTests  a, TestsRanges b
where a.TestId = b.TestId
) c
```

Comment: incorrect syntax near from , incorrect syntax near by expecting BETWEEN , CURRENT , INTEGER or UNBOUNDED.

Comment: @ziadqasem Try now :)

Comment: same errors still not working incorrect syntax near from and near by :)